# C++ Items not being added to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, long-integer, heap-memory

The below procedure is supposed to an Item to an array if the value at the spot in the array is Zero. This way if I needed to dynamically grown the array I can make the new array with the new array element, add all the Items to the array, then initialize the new element to Zero and then populate that element with this code. When I print the array however all I am getting back is the MIN_VALUE for a long. What am I missing?

```
void CResizableArray::SetSize(long lngNewSize)
{

long* palngNewValues;

// Boundary Checks
if (lngNewSize < 0) lngNewSize = 0;


palngNewValues = new long[lngNewSize];

// Initialize empty items in the array to zero
InitializeArray(palngNewValues, lngNewSize);

// Populate the array
PopulateArray(palngNewValues, lngNewSize);

}



void CResizableArray::InitializeArray(long* &palngValues, long lngArraySize)
{

long lngIndex = 0;

// Initialize Array
for (lngIndex = 0; lngIndex < lngArraySize; lngIndex += 1)
{
    // Is there anything in that spot?
    if (*(palngValues + lngIndex) < 0)
    {
        *(palngValues + lngIndex) = 0;
    }

}

// Delete Old array
delete[] m_palngValues;
m_palngValues = 0;

// Assign New array
m_palngValues = palngValues;

//// Assign Size
m_lngArraySize = lngArraySize;

}



long CResizableArray::GetSize()
{
return m_lngArraySize;
}


void CResizableArray::PopulateArray(long* &palngNewValues, long lngArraySize)
{

long lngIndex = 0;

// Populate array
cout << "Please Populate ----------\n" << endl;

// Test value to see if it functions correctly
 *(palngNewValues + 1) = 5; 

for (lngIndex = 0; lngIndex < lngArraySize; lngIndex += 1)
{
    // Check if anything is in this spot
    if (*(palngNewValues + lngIndex) == 0)
    { 
        cout << "Enter value[ " << lngIndex << "]: ";
        cin >> *(palngNewValues + lngIndex);
    }
}
cout << "" << endl;

// Delete Old array
delete[] m_palngValues;
m_palngValues = 0;

// Assign the Values to the new array
m_palngValues = palngNewValues;

// Print
Print(m_palngValues, lngArraySize);

}




void CResizableArray::Print(long* palngValues, const long lngArraySize)
{

long lngIndex = 0;

cout << "Print ----------\n" << endl;
for (lngIndex = 0; lngIndex < lngArraySize; lngIndex += 1)
{
    cout << "Value[ " << lngIndex + 1 << " ] = " << *(palngValues +    lngIndex) << endl;
}
cout << "" << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `*(a + b)` is conventionally written `a[b]`. Also, please just use `std::vector`.

Comment: What does your Print do?

Comment: All of this code is done in two lines: `std::vector<long> v; v.resize(lngArraySize, 5);`

Comment: Why are you mixing I/O in your function?  In addition, we have no idea if what you're passing to this function is valid.  In addition to that, we have no idea what state your object is in when you make this call.  If you aren't getting this function right, no telling what other prerequisites are also faulty.

Comment: You have code duplication in `InitializeArray` and `PopulateArray`.  If you're going to write `PopulateArray`, it should be calling `InitializeArray` first, since the two do the exact same thing.  .